# How do I control web browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I work with VINs once I receive them I go to three websites input them in a cell click search, and save the return results as PDFs I want to write a program to do this for me. NEW TO CODING and looking to get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways.
You tagged Selenium only but you can use Selenium with many programming languages (Python, C#, Java...).
Since Python is the simplest one I'll talk about it.
So, first of all you need to study Python.
You can find many guides and tutorials online. [The official Python's site](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) is a good one.
After that you need to study Selenium:
[this is the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Here you can find almost everything you need to know.

To show you some sample code, for example, this is how you open Firefox and navigate to stackoverflow, wait until the search bar is loaded, locate it, write "test text" in it and press enter to search using Selenium with Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
inputbar = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']"))).send_keys("test text")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

It's pretty straightforward. In this sample code I showed you almost everything is needed to be use to achieve what you want. You just need to study the documentations, that's it :D